# StatusBar not accepting alpha in color I set

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-statusbar

So there may be a bunch of similar-looking questions on here about setting one's `statusBar` color, but I have a slightly different question, which I haven't found a conclusive answer on yet after a few hours of looking...

Basically, how can I set my `statusBar` to accept a color value I set it to which contains some level of alpha in it?

- For instance, I want 90% opacity so it's just barely see-through, but
  also the color of my choice.
- I've already tried methods in my theme, such as

  `<item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/grey_900_transparent</item>`
- `grey_900_transparent` above is defined in my colors.xml as `#E6222222`.

I've also tried setting it programmatically, but the result is the same: **the status bar doesn't want to accept alpha values for slight transparency.**

I've been messing around with setting `android:windowTranslucentStatus:true`, but that doesn't seem to allow any color once it's transparent, let alone any level of transparency other than full-blown 100% see-through.

So what can I do to make my `statusBar` the same color and alpha as my toolbar below it (grey_900 with 90% opacity)?

Thanks for any of your help!

Comment: statusbar color only change on device android >= 5.0

Comment: Yes, Nguyen, I'm aware of that - my current device I'm testing on is on the latest build of Android 9.0.

Answer (score 0):

try to put your color in style.xml chnage colorPrimaryDark

```
 <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/app_purple</item>
```

Comment: Hello, Muhammad, I understand what you are saying. The issue is that it won't accept alpha in the color. So I can still make the `statusBar` accept a color, just no transparency/alpha is working... I'm not sure how to fix this!

Comment: hi as i have set <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#4D074063</item> it has 77 percent alpha it show exactly same color in statusbar with alphe please try to select color having proper alpha from color picker 
#4D074063 is light blue having 77percent alpha